# Make Quantity behave reasonable with Degrees Celsius

Tags: units

When using a `Quantity` with the unit of `"DegreesCelsius"` multiplication doesn't work as expected.
If you have 10 degrees and multiply it by 2 you get 20 degrees instead of the expected 293,15 degrees.
This becomes a real problem if you use the temperature directly in a formula, eg. the ideal gas law.
Example code:

```
t = Quantity[10, "DegreesCelsius"];
T = UnitConvert@t;
UnitConvert[2 * t] // N (* => 293.15 K *)
2 * T // N (* => 566.3 K *)
```

Is there a way to fix this behaviour to work as I expect it to?

Comment: What you are getting is correct. The operations you are doing are not orderless -- order matters.

Comment: How does `UnitConvert` know I didn't want the increment and return 20K?

Comment: @george2079 UnitConvert in this case behaves like `f[x_]:=x+273.15` so the two problems look like `f[2*10] = 20 + 273.15 = 293.15` and `2*f[10] = 2(10 + 273.15) = 566.3`.

Comment: what it did is perfectly clear, the point is the conversion could be absolute or incremental and you ought not expect the computer to guess what you mean.

Comment: From my point of view, there is no meaning in "double the temperature".

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TemperatureUnits.html

Answer (score 2):

Most quantity conversions convert between quantities that have a common zero point (e.g., 0 Kg and 0 Lb are same) and these will work as the OP desires. For temperatures and other quantities where the zero points differ (e.g., 0 °K and 0 °C are not the same), one must be more careful.

I suggest the following workflow.

1. Convert all temperature readings to one system.
2. Do all computations in that uniform system.
3. Back convert any results if necessary.

Comment: [Related topic on Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46240/25453)

Comment: I hope the new `FormulaData` takes this into account